# Why is jQuery causing error in IE8

Tags: jquery, dom, input, internet-explorer-8, htmltext

I've been working with asp.net and jQuery for a long time. It always worked in all browsers. But now in one of my recent application, I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 from Google APIs.

I'm getting an error if I use jQuery with IE8; the same is working with IE 10.

Used debugger, and got this following line creating the error **(line 4, char 26196)**...

```
(1===this.nodeType||11===this.nodeType||9===this.nodeType)&&this.appendChild(e)
```

Error :

```
Unexpected call to method or property access.
```

I'm using jQuery from [Google APIs](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js).

Comment: what's the value in `e`. Also, which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery v2.x doesn't work on <=IE8, so if you're using that version downgrade.

Comment: is your problem available to view online?

Comment: @badZoke :: I already mentioned in the question.. version 1.9.1

Comment: What's the value in `e` then?

Comment: My bad.... Solved.. I was using `.text("myvalue")` to set textbox value... used `.val("myvalue")` instead..

Comment: @KrishanuDey what the hell are you apologizing for?  i had same problem with ieGrrrrrrrrrr8!  +1uv.  now, i'll steal it until you post then i'll delete mine.